# Can I get a PropertyChanged event from a WebService in C#?

Tags: c#, database, web-services, windows-phone-8, inotifypropertychanged

Say I wanted to make an Stock Viewer App for Windows Phone 8, which should present the stock prices for the user live. Then I would have a server with a database containing all the current Stock Prices.

What would the most elegant way to the download stock prices be then?

I can think of two ways (i am pretty new to C#, webservices etc.):

1. The App could just periodically download all the entries from the database and show them in the app - Not very elegant in my opinion.
2. An other way could be to develop a webservice which could provide an interface for downloading only the stocks that have changed. But I don't know if this is possible and how it would be done? Is it possible to bind my local stock data, to some data presented by the web service, and then listen for a PropertyChanged event from the webservice  (with the INotifyPropertyChanged interface), and then update the UI on that event?

Comment: I think only way to avoid polling the web service is to use [Push notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402558(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: Oh, that looks promising - actually it might be just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd put a bit more application logic into the DB if I can make changes to it.

If your database keeps track of the last changed time for each stock it tracks, then when each user queries the database, the database can easily send just the rows which are newer than the last time that user queried.

If the db also has the list of stocks that each user is tracking, then the user query can be just the date/time and the response can be just the stocks which that user is tracking which have also changed, to minimize the network traffic (and improve response time) in the common case.